# Codeigniter Routing Unlimited Paramaters

Tags: codeigniter, parameters, routes, uri, url-routing

I currently have this in my CodeIgniter routes file.
It maps anything with a URI `api/controller/function` to `controller/api_function`.

```
$route['api/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/api_$2/$3/$4/$5/$6';
$route['api/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/api_$2/$3/$4/$5';
$route['api/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/api_$2/$3/$4';
$route['api/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/api_$2/$3';
$route['api/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/api_$2';
```

As you can see, this isn't very efficient. I need a different routes line depending on the number of parameters supplied. Is there a way to automatically pass all parameters along? So hypothetically, I'm looking for something like...

`$route['api/(:any)/(:any)/unlimited parameters'] = '$1/api_$2/unlimited parameters';`

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$route['api/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)'] = '$1/api_$2/$3';
```

It basically checks for two segments (any character but a slash), then anything after that gets appended as parameters to your controller function.

This wouldn't match for routes with *NO* parameters, but it's not hard to do if that's a case you need to handle.

Comment: I'd like some help please.. My url need to be like this: `eng/controller/method/many-params`, where `eng` is any language, so I have set my routes like this: `$route['en-gb/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)'] = '$1/$2/$3/eng';` , but this doesn't seem to work for me, I get a 404 error.. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

This Works perfectly,

```
$route['api/(.*)']='api/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe just this would do:

```
$route['api/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/api_$2';
$route['api/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/api_$2/$3';
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `(:any)` is a greedy reg ex clause, but it looks a lot nicer.  It'd be nice if CI would do a `(:segment)` helper for routes.