# How to create $route rules for url using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have create a subfolder in controller

Structure of Controller folder:

```
--controller
  --backend
    --dashboard.php
    --products.php
  --frontend
    --index.php
    --users.php
```

I have create some rules in route.php file

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'backend/admin_controller/';

$route['admin_panel'] = "backend/admin_controller/dashboard";
$route['admin_panel/login'] = "backend/admin_controller/index";
$route['admin_panel/(:any)'] = "backend/admin_controller/$1";
```

This is working perfectly when i open any link like:

```
http://localhost/Demo_app/admin_panel/products
http://localhost/Demo_app/admin_panel/dashboard
```

These are working fine but when i pass parameters to update product it gives an error url not found.

For these link (when click on these link)

```
http://localhost/Demo_app/admin_panel/add_product/69 
http://localhost/Demo_app/admin_panel/add_product/0/69

/* 69 is product id and 0 is status of product to active or unactive
```

I am confused to create rule for this.

Comment: Have you looked here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: Also what version of Codeigniter you using? If you are using codeigniter 3 default controller will not allow you to have sub folder you will need a MY_Router for that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620564/how-to-routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-using-codeigniter-3/35620718#35620718

Comment: Hello @wolfgang1983, I already do this and i haven't ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for the function specific route

```
$route['admin_panel/add_product/(:any)/(:any)'] = "backend/admin_controller/your_function/$1/$2";
```

Comment: from your given answer i have to create rule for every function. i have already thought it but...

Comment: then have you looked into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455374/codeigniter-routing-unlimited-paramaters

Comment: Thanks to both of you to given you precious time, Hey @Nabin Kunwar I tried you answered link but it didn't work. I apply this `$route['admin_panel/(:any)/([^/]*)'] = "backend/admin_controller/$1/$2"; ` and but when i run without parameter it didn't open this link `http://localhost/Demo_app/admin_panel/category/`