# codeigniter: How to remove only index method in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**I am using a multiple methods in one class.I want to only remove index from url only and other remain same;**

```
www.mysite.com/blog/index
www.mysite.com/blog/index/one/two
www.mysite.com/blog/myblog
www.mysite.com/blog/data_load/one/two
```

Comment: use route it will help you to rewrite the url and it will link to the particular method into the class

Comment: You need to write rules in routes.php 
http://naveedramzan.com/codeigniter-url-rewriting/

Comment: I try  naveedramzan.com/codeigniter-url-rewriting  but when i pass parameter (string) after blog redirect on 404 page

Answer (score 3):

**Hope this will help you :**

in `route.php`

```
$route['blog'] = 'blog/index';
```

Make sure :

in your config file set this :

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/foldername/';

 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: @paradeep  this answer is not enough to answer his question! it will redirect all url starting with blog to blog/index method!

Answer (score 2):

Try this in application/config/routes.php:

```
$route['blog/myblog']                   = 'blog/myblog';
$route['blog/data_load/(.+)/(.+)']      = 'blog/data_load/$1/$2';
$route['blog']                          = 'blog/index';
$route['blog/(.+)']                     = 'blog/index/$1';
$route['blog/(.+)/(.+)']                = 'blog/index/$1/$2';
```

Note: Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

Comment: I try but when i pass parameter (string) after blog redirect on 404 page

Comment: it depend of which number of parameters you need, if you need 1 parameter you must add $route['blog/(.+)']    = 'blog/index/$1/';

Comment: Hi Louk!!How to pass unlimited parameters in route without index??

Comment: @usman in this case  check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455374/codeigniter-routing-unlimited-paramaters

Answer (score 0):

you need to set route for that.

set route in your application/config/routes.php file

$route['project/user/id/(:any)'] = 'project/user/index/id/$1';

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a .htaccess file to handle that.
Create a .htaccess file and paste this code in it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
   #  slashes.
   # If your page resides at
   #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
   # then use
   # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```